# Synchronising MSSQL Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server

I know this is a question that's been asked a lot of times on here, and I've read them all but i'd like your input on our scenario.

We have two physical servers split out to 4 virtual servers web1 web2 sql1 sql2

At the moment we have mirroring enabled on sql1 and 2, this renders sql2 unusable whilst sql1 is online - is this correct? Our projects all have a failover set to sql2 but if sql1 goes down we have to tell it to use the failover in the replication.

Basically what I'm asking, is there a way to have sql1 and sql2 syncronised and both usable so if one goes down the other one just works instantly with no interaction from ourseleves?

What other replication alternatives are there (these are big dbs, probably 60gb+ that change quite often)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mirroring, you can set it up for automatic failover, which would satisfy that requirement.  To make your application aware of it, you set the failover partner property in the connection string.  Then, when a failover happens, the application connects to the partner.  As far as being "usable", you can create a read-only database snapshot of a failover partner, but you can't read from the partner itself.  That's because it's in a constantly recovering state.

If this is something that you're just building out, you might want to consider SQL 2012, which just came out.  It introduces a new feature called "always on" which provides the ability to have read-only failover partners.  And with the changes in licensing, you're already paying for it.

Comment: The only one critical thing in such scenario (mirroring between two servers) - it's witness server. With 2 servers only your *automatic* failover (with witness server on one of them) are virtual and depend from correspondent server live with 50% probability (survive or not survive :) )

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL offers multiple redundancy options as standard: **clustering**, **database mirroring**, **replication**, and **log shipping**.

Which one of these you should use depends entirely on the intended use of the system.

Both clustering and database mirroring offer automatic failover; replication offers multiple-master write capability (though not to a single VIP), and log shipping does nothing automatic but is the most versatile, i.e. you can easily create read-only slaves from it - albeit not in sync with the master.

Looking at your question, it seems you are using mirroring incorrectly to take advantage of automatic failover.

This requires a specific connection-string of the form `Data Source="sql1"; Failover Partner="sql2"`, as well as a working witness server.

See http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008 for details